# send gzip data without unzipping

Tags: python, gzip, at-command, gprs

I am currently working on a script for RaspberryPi using a SIM module to send data to an FTP server. Problem is, some data are quite large and I formatted them into csv files but still, are a bit large to send through GPRS. By compressing them in gz files it reduces the size by 5 which is great, but in order to send data, the only way is to send data line by line. I was wondering if there was a way to send the information of a gzip file without sending the uncompressed data. Here is my code so far:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('/home/pi/src/git/RPI/DATA/*.gz') 
print(list_of_files)

for file_data in list_of_files:
    zipp = gzip.GzipFile(file_data,'rb')
    file_content = zipp.read()
    #array = np.fromstring(file_content, dtype='f4')

    print(len(file_content))
#AT commands to send the file_content to FTP server
```

Here the length returned is the length of the uncompressed data, but i want to be able to retrieve the uncompressed value of the gzip file? Is it doable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems rather confused. Are you trying to ask how to upload binary data over FTP?

Comment: @tripleee Yes and no, I have no idea how to get the binary data of a gzip file. The sending part shouldn't be a problem if i just send the binary data, the FTP will just write it down in a file, i assume...

Comment: Just do a regular `open` on the file in binary mode to read in the raw binary data.

Comment: @tripleee Ok so this actually worked nicely! My FTP server wrote down the binary data as a gzip file and retransmitted the data without any corruption. I wonder if this is the best way though. Works fine anyway! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    zipp = gzip.GzipFile(file_data,'rb')
```

specifically requests unzipping. If you just want to read the bare raw binary `gzip` data, use a regular `open`:

```py
    zipp = open(file_data,'rb')
```

You don't need to read the file into memory to fetch its size, though. The [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) function lets you get information about a file's metadata without opening it.